# Magento 2 display color Attribute value in Minicart

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

I have added a config product which have two attributes size and color.Size attribute is displaying in see detail section but  color is not displaying in mini cart detail section.

Please let me know what we need require to settings to display color attribute value.

Thanks.

Comment: Default Magento attribute details displaying fine in mini cart detail section.
Which Magento version are you using ?